# Python: Retrieve result from inner dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I'm fairly new to python and I don't know how can I retrieve a value from a inner dictionary:

This is the value I have in my variable:

```
variable = {'hosts': 1, 'key':'abc', 'result': {'data':[{'licenses': 2, 'id':'john'},{'licenses': 1, 'id':'mike'}]}, 'version': 2}
```

What I want to do is assign a new variable the number of licenses 'mike' has, for example.

Sorry for such a newbie, and apparent simple question, but I'm only using python for a couple of days and need this functioning asap. I've search the oracle (google) and stackoverflow but haven't been able to find an answer...

PS: Using python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working through it and starting with

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(variable)
{'hosts': 1,
 'key': 'abc',
 'result': {'data': [{'id': 'john', 'licenses': 2},
                     {'id': 'mike', 'licenses': 1}]},
 'version': 2}
```

First, let's get to the `result` dict:

```
>>> result = variable['result']
>>> pprint(result)
{'data': [{'id': 'john', 'licenses': 2}, {'id': 'mike', 'licenses': 1}]}
```

and then to its `data` key:

```
>>> data = result['data']
>>> pprint(data)
[{'id': 'john', 'licenses': 2}, {'id': 'mike', 'licenses': 1}]
```

Now, we have to scan that for the 'mike' dict:

```
>>> for item in data:
...     if item['id'] == 'mike':
...         print item['licenses']
...         break
...
1
```

You could shorten that to:

```
>>> for item in variable['result']['data']:
...     if item['id'] == 'mike':
...         print item['licenses']
...         break
...
1
```

But much better would be to rearrange your data structure like:

```
variable = {
    'hosts': 1,
    'version': 2,
    'licenses': {
        'john': 2,
        'mike': 1,
    }
}
```

Then you could just do:

```
>>> variable['licenses']['mike']
1
```

Comment: Thank you guys, such quick replies! All of you helped me very much. Kirk really answered my question. I was thinking of using for, but wasn't quite getting it due to not being familiar with python. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested references as follows:

```
variable['result']['data'][1]['licenses'] += 1

variable['result'] returns:
{'data':[{'licenses': 2, 'id':'john'},{'licenses': 1, 'id':'mike'}]}

variable['result']['data'] returns:
[{'licenses': 2, 'id':'john'},{'licenses': 1, 'id':'mike'}]

variable['result']['data'][1] returns:
{'licenses': 1, 'id':'mike'}

variable['result']['data'][1]['licenses'] returns:
1

which we then increment using +=1
```

Comment: If you don't know what index 'mike' is at, you can use a list comprehension to get how many licenses he has: `[d['licenses'] for d in variable['result']['data'] if d['id'] == 'mike'][0]`